# Como fazer um Jquery que ao selecionar um radio button, mudo os itens de um select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

estou criando um site html e sou meio iniciante ainda. Estou fazendo uma tela de cadastro de estabelecimentos. Minha problema é: ao selecionar um radio button, quero que mude os dados do select (combobox). 
Exemplo: Radio Button Instituição, quero que mostre no select (Normal, tecnico ou superior), caso mude de opcao, como  Geral mudar o select para parques, compras e etc 
Desde ja agradeço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é simples:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    $('select').val(this.value);
});
```

Como a tua pergunta não tem código a exemplificar deixo um exemplo genérico. Usando `$('select').val(this.value);` estás a dizer ao select para escolher a `option` cujo `value` é o `this.value`. Ora o `this.value` nessa função é o `value` do input.

Em baixo tens um JSON que configura as diferentes possibilidades dos `option` do select, que é montado no momento da escolha do input.

O código que usei foi este:

```js
var opcoes = {
  instituicao: {
    values: ['normal', 'tecnico', 'superior'],
    html: ['Normal', 'Técnico', 'Superior']
  },
  hospital: {
    values: ['clinica', 'particular', 'hospital'],
    html: ['Clínica', 'Particular', 'Hospital']
  },
  geral: {
    values: ['bar', 'parques', 'compras'],
    html: ['Bar', 'Parques', 'Compras']
  }
};
var $select = $('select#tipos');
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var options = opcoes[this.value]; // ler o valor do input e usá-lo como chave do objeto de opções
  if (options) $select.html(''); // esvaziar o select caso haja conteudo
  options.values.forEach(function(value, i) {
    var el = $('<option/>', { // criar um novo elemento
      value: value, // dar-lhe um value
      html: options.html[i] // dar-lhe um texto 
    });
    $select.append(el); // inserir no select
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Instituição
  <input type="radio" name="tipos" value="instituicao" checked>
</label>
<label>Hospital
  <input type="radio" name="tipos" value="hospital">
</label>
<label>Geral
  <input type="radio" name="tipos" value="geral">
</label>

<select name="" id="tipos">
  <option value="normal">Normal</option>
  <option value="tecnico">Tecnico</option>
  <option value="superior">Superior</option>
</select>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ksLoapde/1/