# Como posso alterar uma pagina HTML de forma dinâmica?

Tags: javascript, html, funções, html-select

Bom dia!

Estou a criar uma página html, que servirá para fazer feedback, ou seja servirá para reportar situações especificas ou em determinadas condições pedir ajuda. Acontece que essa página pede de imediato algumas informações essenciais e posteriormente pede para selecionar um tema. Ao selecionar esse tema ela pode chegar a duas situações

1. Apresenta outra selectbox na página para selecionar sub-tema
2. Ou apresenta outro formulário

Estou a recorrer ao javascript para realizar isto, mas não sei muito bem como o fazer, sinto-me com dificuldades. Abaixo mostro o código já entretanto efetuado por mim:

```
<div class="work-post">

                                <div class="work-post-content searchw" id="firstSelect">
                                <form action="" method="post">
                                <select name="select" id="selectFirstHelp" class="formatform search-format" onChange="selectHTML(this)">
                                    <option class="search-format" value="Portugal,PT">Por favor selecione uma categoria</option>
                                    <option class="search-format" value="Reserva/Gestão de Reservas">Reserva/Gestão de Reservas</option>
                                    <option class="search-format" value="Lisboa">Senhor</option>
                                    <option class="search-format" value="Faro">Senhora</option>
                                    <option class="search-format" value="Faro">Meritissima(o)</option>
                                    <option class="search-format" value="Faro">Senhor prof.</option>
                                    <option class="search-format" value="Faro">Senhora prof.</option>
                                  </select>
                                  <script>
                                  function selectHTML(x){
                                    var value = x.value;
                                    var newBox = document.getElementById('selectSecondHelp');
                                    //var getBox = document.getElementById('selectSecondHelp');
                                    if(value=="Reserva/Gestão de Reservas")
                                    {
                                        //Quando seleciono um valor concreto 
                                        //Quero alterar as outras boxes abaixo ... ou mesmo ocultar-las
                                        //Poderei ainda aqui ter de apresentar novo formulário abaixo
                                        function ChangeBox(newBox);     
                                    }

                                  }
                                  function ChangeBox(y)
                                  {
                                     var index=0;
                                     for (index=0; index<=y.length; index++)
                                     {
                                         if(index>=1)
                                         {
                                             alert("Teste");
                                             /*Se primeiro item é [1]*/
                                             if(index[1])
                                                document.getElementById('selectSecondHelp').value="Reservas Atuais";
                                             //Se determinado valor for selecionado posso ter de criar abaixo novo 
                                             //formulário ou adicionar uma terçeira tag select 
                                         }
                                     }
                                  }
                                  </script>
                                </div>                              
                            </div>
```

Abaixo desta "select", tenho outra "select", com mais opções, mas consoante os valores selecionados na primeira "select", eu devo mostrar a segunda "select" alterada, ocultar a segunda "select", ou mesmo ocultar a segunda "select" e criar um novo formulário.

A página: https://www.lufthansa.com/xx/en/Feedback?level1=2&level2=4 , têm um exemplo muito concreto do que pretendo fazer.

Será que podem ajudar-me

Desde já obrigado

Comment: Isso é uma problema relativamente comum e já há algumas respostas sobre isso ([aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10766/129), ou [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126903/129)  entre outras. Podes fazer um JSON (ou um esquema simples) de quais são  as sub-opções? Como envias o formulário? por ajax ou POST de html?

Comment: O formulario está a ser enviado por POST ... Salvo erro